# How to store XML files in SQL database using C#?

Tags: c#, sql

I have an XML file which should be a part of a table in my SQL database (say, name, data and XML).
I prefer not to make a string of it if possible.
What column type should I use for it? I chose XML but I'm not sure how to work with it.

A small code example would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server (if you're using it) has an XML datatype which you can use. I've never used the datatype but we covered it during an SQL Server/.NET course at university.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189887.aspx

Comment: That's what I use.  2005+ required.